# How to make tooltip working with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Q1) I am using the tootltip from twitter bootstrap. I just noticed that its not working when the contents are added with ajax. After lots of googling, the solution seems to trigger the tooltip after ajax request. But in my case this is not possible because I am relying on the built in ajax API's for the framework. Is there any other work around?

```
$('.tootip').tooltip({placement:'left'});
```

Q2) In jQuery on() documentation, the usage is mentioned as

```
$(document).on(event, selector, function(){ //do stuff here })
```

So is this I have to do it?

```
$(document).on('ready', '.tootip', tooltip({placement:'left'}));
```

But its not working.

Comment: can you also include the code that you're using for ajax requests?

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu : its the usual simple $.ajax({type: "GET",.....}) call. the problem is frame works' API doesn't support any external parameters.

Answer (score 1):

A1) One of the options/parameters you give to the ajax call is a callback function that triggered when the ajax call done and succeded. This success callback should initialize the tooltip.
For example, if you are using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your url'
    success: function(result) {
        // do your sruff here. Result holds the return data of the ajax call
    }
});
```

A2) Look at the 3'rd parameter: `function(){ //do stuff here }`. You have to supply a function. Instead, what you have supplied is the result of invoking the function `tooltip({placement:'left'})` which in this case returns an object and not a function. You should do:

```
$(document).on('ready', '.tootip', function() {
    $('.tootip').tooltip({placement:'left'}); 
});
```

**Update regarding your comment:**
Inside a function, whether is a success callback or an event function, you can do whatever you like including call multiple functions:

```
$(document).on('ready', '.tootip', function() {
    // Do many operations as much as you like here
    func1();
    func2();
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'your url'
    success: function(result) {
        // Do many operations as much as you like here
        func1();
        func2();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: is it possible to run two functions with in the same call? Because, I have multiple functions to run in the dom ready instance. So can I club it all together? How?

Comment: Solution 2 not working although its not producing any errors in console

Comment: @user632347: Try solution 2 now. I fixed the function.

Comment: Your solution should. But I am afraid that I cant use it. Because I can only use the API's of the system. There is an API for making the ajax call and process the results. But unfortunately, it doesn't support an extra external functions. So is there any option I can make the tool tip work outside of ajax request?

Comment: @user632347: What do you mean by the api doesn't support extra external functions? are you using jQuery? if yes then my code will work. There is another option to make the ajax call synchronous but this will require adding another parameter to the options of ajax function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19545/discussion-between-user632347-and-naor)